# Analyticity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) =-\dfrac{(z-\sqrt{z^4 - 4z^2)}}{(z^2 + 6z +9)}$ be a complex function. Is it analytic for i) $|z| < 2$, ii) $|z| > 2$ ?

I am not very comfortable with checking analyticity of complex functions involving square roots, so how do I decide analyticity?

Comment: JBuck  Have I edited your function correctly?

Comment: The first things that come to my mind are the "Cauchy-Riemann equations".  The function f(z)= u(x+ iy)+ iv(x+ iy) is analytic if $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.  Can you write this function as "u(x, y)+ iv(x, y)$?

Comment: @amWhy yes, this is correct. Sorry, I have a bad connection.

Comment: @user247327 I can give it a try, but it sure is going to be a bit long. I was wondering if there is a way to decide analyticity for expressions involving roots without resorting to CR.

Comment: When $z=-3$, $|z|=3>2$, but the denominator is $0$